# What is System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo and how do I compare it?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was suprised to see that the actual type of the object I get with `x.GetType().GetProperty("Foo")` is not `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` but `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo`.

I don't see this type documentation in msdn or elsewhere.

My actual problem grows from reference-comparing two properties. I receive a property from third-party lib and compare it with a property which I get with `.GetProperty("Foo")` on the same type. I expected properties to be the same object (and they looks like the same property in "Locals" window while debugging), but they are not (`GetHashCode` result is different). So, I think it can somehow be related with the actual type of the property object which is `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo`.

What is `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo`? How to compare it? Does it behaves the same as usual `PropertyInfo`?

Comment: For your actual problem (properties don't match) I'd recommend coming up with [MCVE] first and than see if you still don't understand that - than ask new question (as this one is about RuntimePropertyInfo)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Isolating the problem helped me and here's I'm asking the next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799386/how-to-compare-same-propertyinfo-with-different-reflectedtype-values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`RuntimePropertyInfo` is an internal implementation. It is a `PropertyInfo`, and in fact, `GetProperty` returns `PropertyInfo` (even if the underlying type is `RuntimePropertyInfo`).

The third-party lib is probably getting the property of a different type than you are?

```
new blah().GetType().GetProperty("Test") == new blah().GetType().GetProperty("Test")
```

Returns true.

Answer (score 3):

`PropertyInfo` is an abstract class while `RuntimePropertyInfo` is the concrete implementation of `PropertyInfo`.

When we call `Type.GetProperties()` or `Type.GetProperty()` they actually returns the `RuntimePropertyInfo`.

The reason you are getting reference not equal could be because of the Type signature difference in the third-party lib.